# ASPXCOMBOBOX Edit Mode inserts NULL VALUES to database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, devexpress, aspxgridview, aspxcombobox

i am creating an asp application, everything seemed to go well until recently when i decided to use ASPXComboBox in gridview, here is how i put it

ComboBox Gets values from customers table ie

**customer_ID  -- this is set as value field**

**Customer_name -- this is set as text field**

there is no problem with displaying values.

my problem is when i am on Edit Mode even though previous values of the column are displayed on the combobox **if i dont change or re-select** the on the combobox it then inserts **NULL** values to the database while updating.

i desperately need help i have searched all over. please reply

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `GridViewDataComboBoxColumn` you can get value like this.

```
GridViewDataComboBoxColumn column = gridView.Columns["ColumnName"] as GridViewDataComboBoxColumn;
string text = column.PropertiesComboBox.Items.FindByValue(e.NewValues["ColumnName"]).Text;
```

Reference : http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q450251

here is the demo preoject:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Attachment/GetAttachment?fileOid=9eb0e913-6fb0-45fe-90d5-76cabdce740e&fileName=Q381107.zip

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q381107